# Best way to integrate openid connect for SPA application

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, openid-connect

I need to integrate OpenId connect for SPA application, without having token id in the URL, can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have some security concerns with having the ID Token in the URL...

I can see two ways to mitigate risks in this case:

- Make sure the OIDC provider redirects to your app using URL fragments instead of via the query string. This ensures that the parameters aren't sent to a server where they might end up in the logs, and should already be the provider's default response mode for implicit flows. If needed you can use `response_mode=fragment` to enforce it.
- You could register a "public" client, but still use the authorization code flow to fetch the ID Token from the token endpoint. In this case you do not present a `client_secret` to the token endpoint (since the client is public). You could consider using [PKCE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) in this flow as well.